# At my end with launchd

Tags: bash, terminal, launchd

Hi all and thanks for reading this. I have the below launchd plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.me.sendip</string>
<key>Program</key>
<string>/Users/me/Documents/sendip.sh</string>
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>60</integer>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/Users/me/Desktop/sendiperr.log</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/Users/me/Desktop/sendip.log</string>
</dict>
```

I also have the below script

```
/Users/me/Documents/Scripts/ip.sh | mail -s "Laptop ip" me@gmail.com
```

I have tried troubleshooting with all the tools [here](http://launchd.info). The script fires with an empty log file on boot but after that nothing.

Someone please help. I am totally stumped and I am sure its something silly. Much appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `/Users/me/Documents/Scripts/ip.sh` **before** it is piped to `mail`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out launchd abandons the sub processes of the script I was trying to run. this is a common problem as it turns out. [Found the answer here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92406/mail-does-not-work-in-scripts-launched-with-launchd)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  I run a script at hourly intervals using the following plist in 10.9.5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.myorg.mytask</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/php</string>
        <string>/path/to/myscript.php</string>
    </array>
    <key>QueueDirectories</key>
    <array/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

That runs every hour at 5 minutes past the hour.

I think for you're looking to run once a minute, right? So your version would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.me.sendip</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/me/Documents/sendip.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>QueueDirectories</key>
    <array/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You may need to start the service by running this command in Terminal: (it will require your password)

```
sudo launchctl load com.me.sendip
```

---

Edit: Here is a script with more explicit logging:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTFILE='/Library/Logs/com.whatever.sendip.log'
ERRFILE='/Library/Logs/com.whatever.sendip.err.log'

SCRIPT='/Users/me/Documents/Scripts/ip.sh'
TARGET_EMAIL='me@gmail.com'
TARGET_SUBJECT='Laptop ip'

VERBOSE=1

if [ "$VERBOSE" -ne 0 ]; then
    date >>"$OUTFILE"
    date >>"$ERRFILE"

    echo -n 'Current user: ' >>"$OUTFILE"
    whoami >>"$OUTFILE"
fi

INFO=$("$SCRIPT" 2>>"$ERRFILE")

echo "$INFO" | mail -s "$TARGET_SUBJECT" "$TARGET_EMAIL" >>"$OUTFILE" 2>>"$ERRFILE"

ERROR_CODE="$?"

if [ "$ERROR_CODE" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Result: Error Code $ERROR_CODE" >>"$OUTFILE"
    echo "Info: $INFO" >>"$OUTFILE"
elif [ "$VERBOSE" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Result: Success" >>"$OUTFILE"
    echo "Info: $INFO" >>"$OUTFILE"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will give it a try. Yes, I am familiar with launchctl and how to load, unload, list, monitor the log file and more. Its a simple script and should work. I can only think I am formatting the plist wrong.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, thanks btw but same result, it fires and doesn't fire again - no email sent. The script fires when I execute it from the command line outside of the plist file and works fine.

Comment: more weirdness. I discovered the path to the file was wrong - still same problem tho. the weird thing is the error didn't show up in the log file. i. don't. understand. the script now fires at the appropriate time, every 60 seconds but still does not send anything out.

Comment: so i think i isolated the problem. mail. mail refuses to be sent from the script but from the command line its fine.

Comment: I ended up writing a more complex script above – it probably doesn't show you anything you haven't already seen in debugging so far.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with which user runs the daemon.

Comment: Folders within /Users/someuser are usually no-read no-listings to other uses, so files in /Users/me/Desktop aren't visible to other users without root privileges.  Might be worth storing the log file elsewhere?  Would also be worth creating them and making them world-writable if there's any doubt of the daemon user.

e.g. `sudo touch /Library/Logs/com.whatever.sendip.log && sudo chmod a+rw /Library/Logs/com.whatever.sendip.log`